# How to configure emacs by using this file?

Tags: emacs, python

From http://public.halogen-dg.com/browser/alex-emacs-settings/.emacs?rev=1346 I got:

```
(setq load-path (cons "/home/alex/.emacs.d/" load-path))     
(setq load-path (cons "/home/alex/.emacs.d/configs/" load-path))     
(defconst emacs-config-dir "~/.emacs.d/configs/" "")

(defun load-cfg-files (filelist)
  (dolist (file filelist)
    (load (expand-file-name 
       (concat emacs-config-dir file)))
    (message "Loaded config file:%s" file)
    ))


(load-cfg-files '("cfg_initsplit"
         "cfg_variables_and_faces"
         "cfg_keybindings"
         "cfg_site_gentoo"
         "cfg_conf-mode"
         "cfg_mail-mode"
         "cfg_region_hooks"
         "cfg_apache-mode"
         "cfg_crontab-mode"
         "cfg_gnuserv"
         "cfg_subversion"
         "cfg_css-mode"
         "cfg_php-mode"
         "cfg_tramp"
         "cfg_killbuffer"
         "cfg_color-theme"
         "cfg_uniquify"
         "cfg_tabbar"
         "cfg_python"
         "cfg_ack"
         "cfg_scpaste"
         "cfg_ido-mode"
         "cfg_javascript"
         "cfg_ange_ftp"
         "cfg_font-lock"
         "cfg_default_face"
         "cfg_ecb"
         "cfg_browser"
         "cfg_orgmode"
;        "cfg_gnus"
;        "cfg_cyrillic"
         ))


; enable disabled advanced features
(put 'downcase-region 'disabled nil)
(put 'scroll-left 'disabled nil)
(put 'upcase-region 'disabled nil)

; narrow cursor
;(setq-default cursor-type 'hbar)

(cua-mode)

; highlight current line
(global-hl-line-mode 1)


; AV: non-aggressive scrolling 
(setq scroll-conservatively 100)
(setq scroll-preserve-screen-position 't)
(setq scroll-margin 0)


(custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(ange-ftp-passive-host-alist (quote (("redbus2.chalkface.com" . "on") ("zope.halogen-dg.com" . "on") ("85.119.217.50" . "on"))))
 '(blink-cursor-mode nil)
 '(browse-url-browser-function (quote browse-url-firefox))
 '(browse-url-new-window-flag t)
 '(buffers-menu-max-size 30)
 '(buffers-menu-show-directories t)
 '(buffers-menu-show-status nil)
 '(case-fold-search t)
 '(column-number-mode t)
 '(cua-enable-cua-keys nil)
 '(user-mail-address "alex@halogen-dg.com")
 '(cua-mode t nil (cua-base))
 '(current-language-environment "UTF-8")
 '(file-name-shadow-mode t)
 '(fill-column 79)
 '(grep-command "grep --color=never -nHr -e * | grep -v .svn --color=never")
 '(grep-use-null-device nil)
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(initial-frame-alist (quote ((width . 80) (height . 40))))
 '(initsplit-customizations-alist (quote (("tabbar" "configs/cfg_tabbar.el" t) ("ecb" "configs/cfg_ecb.el" t) ("ange\\-ftp" "configs/cfg_ange_ftp.el" t) ("planner" "configs/cfg_planner.el" t) ("dired" "configs/cfg_dired.el" t) ("font\\-lock" "configs/cfg_font-lock.el" t) ("speedbar" "configs/cfg_ecb.el" t) ("muse" "configs/cfg_muse.el" t) ("tramp" "configs/cfg_tramp.el" t) ("uniquify" "configs/cfg_uniquify.el" t) ("default" "configs/cfg_font-lock.el" t) ("ido" "configs/cfg_ido-mode.el" t) ("org" "configs/cfg_orgmode.el" t) ("gnus" "configs/cfg_gnus.el" t) ("nnmail" "configs/cfg_gnus.el" t))))
 '(ispell-program-name "aspell")
 '(jabber-account-list (quote (("alex@halogen-dg.com"))))
 '(jabber-nickname "AVK")
 '(jabber-password nil)
 '(jabber-server "halogen-dg.com")
 '(jabber-username "alex")
 '(remember-data-file "~/Plans/remember.org")
 '(safe-local-variable-values (quote ((dtml-top-element . "body"))))
 '(save-place t nil (saveplace))
 '(scroll-bar-mode (quote right))
 '(semantic-idle-scheduler-idle-time 432000)
 '(show-paren-mode t)
 '(svn-status-hide-unmodified t)
 '(tool-bar-mode nil nil (tool-bar))
 '(transient-mark-mode t)
 '(truncate-lines f)
 '(woman-use-own-frame nil))

; не легче набрать y или n?
(fset 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p)


(custom-set-faces
  ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(compilation-error ((t (:foreground "tomato" :weight bold))))
 '(cursor ((t (:background "red1"))))
 '(custom-variable-tag ((((class color) (background dark)) (:inherit variable-pitch :foreground "DarkOrange" :weight bold))))
 '(hl-line ((t (:background "grey24"))))
 '(isearch ((t (:background "orange" :foreground "black"))))
 '(message-cited-text ((((class color) (background dark)) (:foreground "SandyBrown"))))
 '(message-header-name ((((class color) (background dark)) (:foreground "DarkGrey"))))
 '(message-header-other ((((class color) (background dark)) (:foreground "LightPink2"))))
 '(message-header-subject ((((class color) (background dark)) (:foreground "yellow2"))))
 '(message-separator ((((class color) (background dark)) (:foreground "thistle"))))
 '(region ((t (:background "brown"))))
 '(tooltip ((((class color)) (:inherit variable-pitch :background "IndianRed1" :foreground "black")))))
```

The above is a python emacs configure file. Where should I put it to use it? And, are there any other changes I need to make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a .emacs file, its a configuration file for emacs.  Generally you place the file in your home directory /home/your-user-name/ or you can place it in the sub-directory /home/your-user-name/.emacs.d/ in your home directory.

Also one thing to note about this .emacs file is that it is expecting to find a bunch of additional configuration files in /home/your-user-name/.emacs.d/configs.  So you will need to download those files as well from the original URL.

Additionally the first two lines hard-code the path /home/alex as a load-path, so if alex is not your user name, you will have to change those two lines.